# Send JSON data from express to html NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Hello all i'm new with node so here my use case i want to post data to my express app and show it on a html page is that possible with nodeJs ?

Here my code

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html', {data: req.body});
})
```

Comment: yes that is possible

Comment: okay thanks but how can i get this data in my html file i tried var data = {{data}} but didn't worked

Comment: @Craicerjack this should be the accepted answer

Comment: You should read the documentation - http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: You can try EJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tutorials showing how to do that. I would recommend first you understand how HTTP protocol works (The message structure : https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html). Then go dive into node and exchange data through requests and responses. I'd recommend body-parser to arrange the data format between the two sides. Also read the express documentation. Hope it helps.